# Contribution of a predictor in Nonparametric regression

Tags: r, regression, nonparametric, predictor, kernel-smoothing

Is there an equivalent to a beta weights in a nonparametric regression?

I am using the NP package in R and running a local linear regression where my bandwidth estimates are produced using least squared method.

I have run the significance test but this just provides p values.

Do I need to rerun the regression leaving out each predictor and compare the R squared value?

Thanks

Comment: If you make multiple regression runs that leave out different predictors, I suggest calculating the R-squared, RMSE, and peak magnitude of error for the run. These each answer a different question: R-squared tells you the explained variance, RMSE is similar to "average size of error", and peak magnitude tells you the worst-case individual error.